# NReco FFMPEG concat failure

Tags: c#, video-processing, nreco

I'm trying to concatenate two videos taken (should be the same frame rate etc.) with `NReco.VideoConverter` and I'm getting this error

> NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegException: 'Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_concat_0 (exit code: 1)'

I'm just trying out the lib for the first time so I'm unfamiliar with the error.

Does anyone have any experience using this library? If so, what error could that be?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you tried to use `FFMpegConverter.ConcatMedia` method; this is actually an alias for ffmpeg command that uses [concat filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate). It expects that all input video chunks have the same frame size, frame rate and media streams: if first video file has both video and audio, all next chunks also should have video and audio.

It is good idea to test ffmpeg commands from the command line first (with ffmpeg.exe), and only after that transfer them to C# cod that uses `FFMpegConverter` class. In some cases, if you need full control over 'contact' filter, it is better to use `ConvertMedia` method with custom set of ffmpeg arguments - they may be provided by ConvertSettings parameter (CustomInputArgs/CustomOutputArgs properties).